# Custom error code with Spring ConstrainValidation

Tags: java, spring

I have actually a solution to validate fields with costum boilerplate of code.

I would like to create annotations to simplify that, but I can't find how to manage custom Error code for my validation.

Does anyone know a solution ?

Comment: Based on [that tuto](https://mydevgeek.com/spring-boot-rest-web-service-part-3-exception-handling-validation-using-controlleradvice-valid-custom-annotations/), I tried to add a field on my annotation, but I can't see how to get It in my advice.

Comment: Check if this helps http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Comment: please share some code and what you have tried?